# Ionic: geolocation not working on Android

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

**THE SITUATION:**

I am building an hybrid app with Ionic Framework. I need to get user location.

I found a cordova plugin called [Geolocation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation)

It works perfectly inside the browser, but it doesn't work testing the app in the phone (Android) or inside an emulator (Genymotion).

I know there are similar questions on SO but the solutions aren't working for me.

**THE CODE:**

```
var options = { timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true };

$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position)
{
    $scope.userLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    $scope.map.markers = [{
        id: "first",
        location_data: {
        latitude: 45.3694868,
        longitude: -73.9803275
        }
    },{
        id: "second",
        icon: "img/blue_marker.png",
        location_data: {
        latitude: $scope.userLocation.H,
        longitude: $scope.userLocation.L
        }
    }];

}, function(error){

    alert('error geolocation');


});
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**ATTEMPTS:**

As read in other SO answers, I have tried several other combinations regarding the options, but none of them did the trick.

```
var options = {timeout: 15000, enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 5000};

var options = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false, maximumAge: 0};

var options = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 0};
```

**ERROR MESSAGES IN CONSOLE:**

```
k: no valid models attribute found 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at k.didQueueInitPromise 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'gManager' of undefined
at Object.fn 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Object.fn

PositionError {message: "Timeout expired", code: 3, PERMISSION_DENIED: 1, POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: 2, TIMEOUT: 3}
```

**THE QUESTION:**

Why Geolocation is working fine in the browser but not on Android?
What is the exact reason?
How can i make it properly working?

Thank you!!

Comment: Did you specified any permissions in AndroidManifest file ?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question.

Comment: Why are you talking about the `Globalization` plugin? It has nothing to do with geolocation. Try to `console.log` the error, to see what is the problem, and tell us the result. If you set `enableHighAccuracy` to false, what happens?

Comment: Sorry, i confuse them while making in the question. Globalization was for the multilanguage. Anyhow i have Geolocation installed. The situation is the same. But i edit the question including the error from the console.

Comment: I just downgrade it into this environment:

Cordova CLI: 4.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.2
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.16
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.3
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.6.1

and, it works!

Answer (score 1):

it depends on your cordova version. update it "npm update -g cordova" to latest .
If this not work try using this method navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/geolocation/
Please **do not write** the import statement.

### Add Geolocation ##

$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation

### How to use it

Directly and without importing.

```js
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
 //resp.coords.latitude
 //resp.coords.longitude
})

let watch = Geolocation.watchPosition();
watch.subscribe((data) => {
 //data.coords.latitude
 //data.coords.longitude
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using cordova geolocation plugin.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess,onError,options);
```

And I was also facing the same problem, It wasn't working in genymotion. Setting enableHighAccuracy to true worked for me like below.

```
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  maximumAge: 0
};
```